# Magento 2: knockout function automatically call without click

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I have call one function on button click but right now its call on page load automatically. It should be call only when click on button.
Knockout js

```
 define([
  'ko',
  'uiComponent'
], function (ko,Component) {
  'use strict';
   return Component.extend({
      firstname:ko.observable(),
      initialize:function(config){
          this._super();
      },
      getTest:function(){
        console.log('somi');
      }
   });  
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="text: firstname"></div>
<button data-bind="click: getTest()">click me</button>
```

is any idea, please share.

Answer (score 1):

got the solution:

Remove brackets from function and its worked :)

```
<button data-bind="click: getTest">click me</button>
```

Comment: what if you have to pass arguments to the function?